# Is it a BUG with fink 1.12 batch mode?

Tags: apache-flink

when I use Flink 1.12 batch, my code:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);

        DataStream<Person> flintstones = env.fromElements(
                new Person("Fred", 35),
                new Person("Wilma", 35),
//                new Person("Pebbles", 2),
                new Person("Pebbles", 2)
        );

        flintstones.keyBy(person -> person.age)
                .reduce((a, b) -> {
                    a.age = a.age + b.age; return a;
                }).print();

        env.execute();
    }

    public static class Person {
        public String name;
        public Integer age;
        public Person() {};

        public Person(String name, Integer age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        };

        public String toString() {
            return this.name.toString() + ": age " + this.age.toString();
        };
    }

}
```

i think the result should be:

```
Fred: age 70
Pebbles: age 2
```

but the result is:

```
11> Fred: age 70
```

lost `Pebbles: age 2`.
if i uncomment `new Person("Pebbles", 2),` i can get the right result:

```
1> Pebbles: age 4
11> Fred: age 70
```

and if i use dataSet, i can also get the right result. code:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataSet<Person> flintstones = env.fromElements(
                new Person("Fred", 35),
                new Person("Wilma", 35),
//                new Person("Pebbles", 2),
                new Person("Pebbles", 2)
        );

        flintstones.groupBy(person -> person.age)
                .reduce((a, b) -> {
                    a.age = a.age + b.age; return a;
                }).print();

//        env.execute();
    }
```

result:

```
Fred: age 70
Pebbles: age 2
```

The code is only used for testing and has no business significance.Is this a BUG or am I misreading it?
my maven

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-clients_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-queryable-state-runtime_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in reduce in batch execution mode, which has been fixed in master and the fix will be included in 1.12.1. See [FLINK-20764](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20764).

Comment: @Tengtuox Happy to help. If you will accept my answer, that will indicate that your question has been resolved.